# How to do press and release in UI Tests?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UITest that runs whenever fastlane is called to get my apps screenshots. I have segment of code as follows:

```
app.children(matching: .window)
        .element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element(boundBy: 1).children(matching: .other)
        .element(boundBy: 3).press(forDuration: 1.8)

    snapshot("EffectsScreenshot")
```

However, this does not create the effect I would like. Instead, I would like to press the element, take the snapshot, and then release the press from the screen. Is there any way of currently accomplishing this in UI Tests?

Comment: So, I guess that you have some code that does something when you release finger from screen? Can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to use press for duration and perform actions *during that press duration* unfortunately.